# Tail for moving sprite andengine

Tags: java, android, sprite, andengine

I want to add a tail to a moving sprite, i've read on the internet that i should use particles, but they dont give the smooth line as in my example. Does anybody have a suggestion how to do this?

[image]

Here is an example with particles, which is not how i want it!

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a picture of the result when using particles?

Comment: @Jong I added a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw continuous connected lines by providing preX, PreY and nextX and nextY points 
here is the code to draw [lines](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/drawing-lines-scribble-with-touch-t3072-10.html)  also you can draw multi point paths. here is the sample [code](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/drawing-a-line-made-up-from-multiple-points-t7536.html)